# How to use rmagick in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rmagick

I am a new bee in Ruby on Rails. I want to do image manipulation in my rails project using rmagick. But am am confused how to do it. I have practiced 'rmagick' on console. But now i want to manipulate an uploaded image in my rails project using rmagick. help me in this??

Comment: Please specify what action you need to get done, your question is very broad.
Use this tutorial.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/374-image-manipulation?autoplay=true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably better of using Carrierwave or PaperClip gem unless you plan to do something really exotic.

Essentially these 2 use imagemagic in the background, but have automated the common actions like image uploading, resizing and avaratar user pics.

As added bonus unlike rmagic gem they come with good documentation to get started.

Here you go.

1. PaperClip https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip
2. CarrierWave https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

That said if you want to use Rmagic here is an example of image resizing controller method.

```
def resize_images
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'RMagick'
    include Magick
    require "open-uri"

    file_url = open('URL to image')
    save_path = "/"

    f = File.new( File.join(save_path, file_url), "wb")
    f.write file_url.read 
    f.close

    image = Magick::Image.read(file_url).first
    image.change_geometry!("1500x150") { |cols, rows, img|
        newimg = img.resize(cols, rows)
        newimg.write("newfilename.jpg")
    }
end
```